# When I close a window in Vim, how do I change the window my cursor moves to?

Tags: vim

I often have several windows open at once in Vim: one is my code, one is a side-bar, one is the open quickfix window on bottom.

Whenever I close the bottom window with `<C-W> C`, the cursor is moved to the side-bar, as it is on the left.

Is there a way I can make the cursor instead move to the main window on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remap the close command to always go back to the previous window:

```
:nnoremap <C-w>c <C-w>c<C-w>p
```

Answer (score 1):

You said that the bottom window is quickfix. You don't have to move your cursor to that window, then type `C-W c` to close it. You could leave your cursor in your main window (above one), then `:cclose`, the quickfix window gets closed, and your cursor stays in where it was.

`:h cclose` to see detail. also you could make a mapping for that if use that often.

I am not sure if you would accept this.

Comment: Minor note that `:ccl` is an abbreviation for `:cclose`.  Just in case that makes this answer more palatable.